# I kept getting keyerror but I've test it outside and it worked

Tags: python, keyerror

I want to create a dictionary which uses the values from other dictionary, and the values are lists.

```
    demand={demandpoint[i]:coorD[i] for i in range(50)}
    Launchstation={Launchstationpoint[i]:coorL[i] for i in range(50)}
    Rechargestation={Rechargestationpoint[i]:coorR[i] for i in range(50)}
```

these keys and the values look like:

```
    {1: [67, 3],2: [27, 49],.....
```

and now I want to use the values to calculate, and create a new dictionary(the last line of the paragraph below is actually parallel with the (s1=math....) line)

demandpoint[]&Launchstationpoint[] are two lists I set previously

```
    dicttt={}
    for i in range(50):
        for j in range(50):
            s1=math.sqrt((((demand[i])[0])-((Launchstation[j])[0]))**2+(((demand[i])[1])-((Launchstation[j])[1])**2))
    dicttt.setdefault((demandpoint[i],Launchstationpoint[j]),s1)
```

but it keep telling me

```
    keyerror:0
```

I've tested

```
    print(demand[1])
    print((demand[1])[0])
```

and the results are:

```
    [28, 14]
    28
```

but I guess I can't do it that way here?
how should I do it?

Comment: You pretty much just need to print more things until you find it. If you want help figuring out where the mistake is, it would be helpful to have a complete example that we can run.

Comment: `s1=math.sqrt((((demand[i])[0])-((Launchstation[j])[0]))**2+(((demand[i])[1])-((Launchstation[j])[1])**2))
    dicttt.setdefault((demandpoint[i],Launchstationpoint[j]),s1)` this line is pretty difficult to debug. Try to split up individual parts and assign to some variables and then do `sqrt` operation. That way you would be able to figure out what exactly went wrong in which line.

Comment: One more thing. The `demand` is a dict. And when you use `demand[i]` with i generated using `range` your assumption is that all continues numbers from 0 to n (n being input to range) is present in your dict. Is that a valid assumption. Much better way to iterate dicts are `for i in demand.keys()` and use `demand[i]` to get values

Comment: The dictionaries you create might not have keys `0` to `49` but you expect them to later, E.g `demand[i]`. The first key in `demand` is `demandpoint[0]`. We don't know what that is.

Comment: hey guys, I found out that my keys for the new dictionary are actually (1,51) not (50) .Pretty stupid mistake, thanks for your help!